# What in the world is the attribute "__class__" in python

Tags: python, class

I have a question about `__class__` in python.

The documentation says that `__class__` is the class to which a class instance belongs. So I conducted a series of experiments:

```
class counter:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
            self.__class__.count += 1

NewCounter1 = counter()
print NewCounter1.count   #The result is 1
NewCounter2 = counter()
print NewCounter2.count   #The result is 2
print NewCounter2.__class__.count is NewCounter2.count  #result: True
```

Everything goes well.

Then I enter code as follows:

```
NewCounter2.__class__.count = 3

print NewCounter1.count                    #result:3
print NewCounter1.__class__.count      #result:3
print NewCounter2.count                    #result:3
print NewCounter2.__class__.count      #result:3
print NewCounter2.__class__.count is NewCounter2.count      #result: True
```

From the code above, I thought that maybe `NewCounter1.count` equals `NewCounter1`, or `__class__.count`, but the following code surprised me:

```
NewCounter2.count = 5

print NewCounter1.count                 #result:3
print NewCounter1.__class__.count   #result:3
print NewCounter2.count                 #result:5
print NewCounter2.__class__.count   #result:3
print NewCounter2.__class__.count is NewCounter2.count       #result: False
```

Why has `NewCounter2.count` changed but `NewCounter2.__class__.count` remained at 3? What's more, when I changed `NewCounter2.count`, `NewCounter2.__class__.count is NewCounter2.count` became `False`. What in the world is the attribute `__class__` ？

Comment: +1 for long-winded questions.

Comment: Also, `is` does not do what you think it does here, especially with regards to small integers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> "From codes above, I thought that maybe NewCounter1.count equals NewCounter1. _class_.count"

The problem is that at the moment of this sentence in your question, after the only instructions:

```
NewCounter1 = counter()
NewCounter2 = counter()
NewCounter2.__class__.count = 3
```

having created **NewCounter1** and **NewCounter2**
and having modified the class attribute **counter.count**,
 there are no objects    **NewCounter1.count** nor **NewCounter2.count**   in existence, and then *"equals"* has no real meaning.

.

See the creation of **NewCounter1** and just after:

```
class counter:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.count += 1

print 'counter.count BEFORE ==',counter.count  # The result is 0
NewCounter1 = counter()
print '\nNewCounter1.__dict__ ==',NewCounter1.__dict__  # The result is {}
print 'NewCounter1.count    ==',NewCounter1.count # The result is 1
print 'counter.count AFTER  ==',counter.count  # The result is 1
```

**NewCounter._*dict*_** is the namespace of the instance **NewCounter1**
`print NewCounter1.count`   prints the same as `print counter.count`
However, 'count' (the string 'count') isn't in the namespace of **NewCounter1**, that is to say there is no attribute **count** in the namespace of the created instance !

How is it possible ?

That's because the instance is created without assignement to a 'count' identifier inside the **_*init*_**
-> there is no real creation of any attribute as a field in **NewCounter1**, that is to say no creation of INSTANCE attribute.

The consequence is that when the instruction
`print 'NewCounter1.count   ==',NewCounter1.count`
is evaluated, the interpreter doesn't find an instance attribute in the **NewCounter1** 's namespace,  and then goes to the class of the instance to search for the key 'count' in this class's namespace; there it finds 'count' as a key of a CLASS attribute and can take the VALUE of the object **counter.count** as a VALUE to display in response to the instruction.

> A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.
>   http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

So, `NewCounter1.count equals NewCounter1.__class__.count` here means that the VALUE  for NewCounter1.count, even if this one doesn't really exist, is the VALUE of the class attribute **NewCounter1. *class*.count**. Here "is" is the english verb, not the feature **is** of the language that tests the identities of two objects, and it means 'is considered to have '

When `NewCounter2.__class__.count = 3` is executed, only the class attribute **counter.count** is affected. The namespaces of **NewCounter1** and **NewCounter2** remain empty and the same mechanism of going to the class to find the value of **counter.count** is followed.

.

At the end, when `NewCounter2.count = 5` is executed , this time an INSTANCE attribute  **count** is created as a field in the **NewCounter2** object and 'count' appears in the namespace of  **NewCounter2** .
It doesn't overwrite anything, because there was nothing preceding in the instance's `__dict__`
No other change affects **NewCounter1** and **counter.count**

The following code shows more explicitly the underlying events during execution:

```
from itertools import islice

class counter:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        print ('  |  counter.count   first == %d  at  %d\n'
               '  |     self.count   first == %d  at  %d')\
               % (counter.count,id(counter.count),
                  self.count,id(self.count))

        self.__class__.count += 1 # <<=====

        print ('  |  counter.count  second == %d  at  %d\n'
               '  |     self.count  second == %d  at  %d\n'
               '  |  id(counter) == %d   id(self) == %d')\
               % (counter.count,id(counter.count),
                  self.count,id(self.count),
                  id(counter),id(self))



def display(*li):
    it = iter(li)
    for ch in it:
        nn = (len(ch)-len(ch.lstrip('\n')))*'\n'
        x = it.next()
        print '%s ==  %s %s' % (ch,x,'' if '__dict__' in ch else 'at '+str(id(x)))



display('counter.count AT START',counter.count)


print ('\n\n----- C1 = counter() ------------------------')
C1 = counter()
display('C1.__dict__',C1.__dict__,
        'C1.count ',C1.count,
        '\ncounter.count ',counter.count)


print ('\n\n----- C2 = counter() ------------------------')
C2 = counter()
print ('  -------------------------------------------') 
display('C1.__dict__',C1.__dict__,
        'C2.__dict__',C2.__dict__,
        'C1.count ',C1.count,
        'C2.count ',C2.count,
        'C1.__class__.count',C1.__class__.count,
        'C2.__class__.count',C2.__class__.count,
        '\ncounter.count ',counter.count)


print '\n\n------- C2.__class__.count = 3 ------------------------\n'
C2.__class__.count = 3
display('C1.__dict__',C1.__dict__,
        'C2.__dict__',C2.__dict__,
        'C1.count ',C1.count,
        'C2.count ',C2.count,
        'C1.__class__.count',C1.__class__.count,
        'C2.__class__.count',C2.__class__.count,
        '\ncounter.count ',counter.count)


print '\n\n------- C2.count = 5 ------------------------\n'
C2.count = 5
display('C1.__dict__',C1.__dict__,
        'C2.__dict__',C2.__dict__,
        'C1.count ',C1.count,
        'C2.count ',C2.count,
        'C1.__class__.count',C1.__class__.count,
        'C2.__class__.count',C2.__class__.count,
        '\ncounter.count ',counter.count)
```

result

```
counter.count AT START ==  0 at 10021628


----- C1 = counter() ------------------------
  |  counter.count   first == 0  at  10021628
  |     self.count   first == 0  at  10021628
  |  counter.count  second == 1  at  10021616
  |     self.count  second == 1  at  10021616
  |  id(counter) == 11211248   id(self) == 18735712
C1.__dict__ ==  {} 
C1.count  ==  1 at 10021616

counter.count  ==  1 at 10021616


----- C2 = counter() ------------------------
  |  counter.count   first == 1  at  10021616
  |     self.count   first == 1  at  10021616
  |  counter.count  second == 2  at  10021604
  |     self.count  second == 2  at  10021604
  |  id(counter) == 11211248   id(self) == 18736032
  -------------------------------------------
C1.__dict__ ==  {} 
C2.__dict__ ==  {} 
C1.count  ==  2 at 10021604
C2.count  ==  2 at 10021604
C1.__class__.count ==  2 at 10021604
C2.__class__.count ==  2 at 10021604

counter.count  ==  2 at 10021604


------- C2.__class__.count = 3 ------------------------

C1.__dict__ ==  {} 
C2.__dict__ ==  {} 
C1.count  ==  3 at 10021592
C2.count  ==  3 at 10021592
C1.__class__.count ==  3 at 10021592
C2.__class__.count ==  3 at 10021592

counter.count  ==  3 at 10021592


------- C2.count = 5 ------------------------

C1.__dict__ ==  {} 
C2.__dict__ ==  {'count': 5} 
C1.count  ==  3 at 10021592
C2.count  ==  5 at 10021568
C1.__class__.count ==  3 at 10021592
C2.__class__.count ==  3 at 10021592

counter.count  ==  3 at 10021592
```

.

An interesting thing to do is to add an instruction
`self.count = counter.count`
BEFORE the line
`self.__class__.count += 1 # <<=====`
to observe the changing of results

.

In conclusion, the point wasn't concerning `__class__` but the mechanism of searching an attribute , and this mechanism is misleading when ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and enthusiasm. I don't know what to say but thank you. I really know the machanism of this. What you say is very detailed. Thanks once again!

Comment: Thank you. I like to examine things in detail and I like to write something trying to produce a clear text with as little ambiguities and vague wording as possible. The first improves one's comprehension and the second allows to test if this comprehension is solid. I wish you good time on SO.

Comment: @eyquem Thank you very much. This answer is so information rich that I will have to read it at least once more to really get it. I wish all answers were of such high quality.

Comment: @eyquem If you don't mind giving a tip, what do you do about this situation?: 


First, a question is asked. 


Next, I start to write up a very detailed answer such as this. Next, while I am doing so, someone else answers quickly and the asker accepts their answer. Finally, I am left with nothing :( . What are some ways to solve that situation? Since you have the accepted answer and it's detailed, perhaps you have the solution? I know this is random, but thanks in advance.

Comment: @eyquem, why do you compute 'nn' in the display() function ?

Comment: I thought it was only JavaScript that behaved like this. Thank you for shattering my illusions. _*sob*_

Answer (score 10):

This line:

```
NewCounter2.__class__.count = 3
```

changes the static `count` of `counter`, but here:

```
NewCounter2.count = 5
```

`NewCounter2` now has its own `count` attribute that hides the static `count`;
so that line has no effect on `NewCounter1`.
This is also why `NewCounter2.__class__.count != NewCounter2.count`.

Comment: The confusion seems to arise because while can you _get_ the attribute `counter.count` on an instance of `counter`, you can't _set_ the attribute `counter.count` directly on an instance of `counter`.

Answer (score 3):

Rebinding (i.e. assigning) an attribute on an object with the same name as an attribute on the class shadows the attribute on the class. The object is always checked for attributes first, followed by the classes in MRO order.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
NewCounter2.count = 5
```

Creates new **instance level** attribute of `NewCounter2`. After that you accessing two different attributes (`NewCounter2.count` - instance level attr and `NewCounter2.__class__.count` - class level attr) that's cause 'strange' behaviour'.