# Django - How to filter the data in save method for the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to filter the data in save method by using the same model.

Let us assume I have BestHotel Model

```
class BestHotel(models.Model):

    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hotel_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        if self.pk:
            ---- I wanna get matched data object.
                  But The below code is not allowing It saying
                  global name "BestHotel" is not defined 
                   **BestHotel.objects.get(slug=xxxx)** -------

       super(BestHotel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`self.__class__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060751/what-in-the-world-is-the-attribute-class-in-python) to get to the model class:

```
self.__class__.objects.get(slug=xxxx)
```

<sup>Though, I have a strong feeling that if you are doing smth like this in django, you are probably missing smth and doing smth wrong.</sup>

Comment: perfect..i had forgot to add *objects* in self.__class__