# use __name__ as attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, attributes

I was reading a book about python class, but
I found something strange in an example when defining `__str__`:

```
__class__.__name__
```

The full code is :

```
def __str__(self):
return '{} {},HP:{},xp:{}'.format(self.col.title(),self.__class__.__name__,self.points,self.exp)
```

You can use `self.class` and it would work, although the writer does comment about this part.
He says `.__name__` is the string version of the class name.
Can someone explain to me what that means ?

Comment: Take a look at [What in the world is the attribute “__class__” in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060751/what-in-the-world-is-the-attribute-class-in-python)

Comment: i all ready look at it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's say you define a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__)
```

If you try to print that class, look what you get:

```
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> print(instance)
__main__.MyClass
```

That is because the string version of the class includes the module that it is defined in.  In this case, it is defined in the module that is currently being executed, the shell, so it shows up as `__main__.MyClass`.  If we use `self.__class__.__name__`, however:

```
class MyClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

instance = MyClass()
print(instance)
```

it outputs:

```
MyClass
```

The `__name__` attribute of the class does not include the module.

Note: The `__name__` attribute gives the name originally given to the class.  Any copies will keep the name.  For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

SecondClass = MyClass

instance = SecondClass()
print(instance)
```

output:

```
MyClass
```

That is because the `__name__` attribute is defined as part of the class definition.  Using `SecondClass = MyClass` is just assigning another name to the class.  It does not modify the class or its name in any way.